# load balancer is not allowing traffic back

Tags: azure, unix, routes, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer

facing a weird issue. our complete infra is on Azure.

1) we have a service running on one port (9443). and it is running on 2 boxes, box1 and box2.

2) we have frontended it with LB on a azure, and i have created LB rule for that port.

3) now from any other box on azure, i can do curl -I -v https://dns.of.lb:9443/blah/blah  and i get 304 in return.

4) i can access LB DNS from browser and it works perfectly.

issue is: when i run same curl command from box1 or box2, I am not getting anything. it seems curl get stuck, or LB doesnt let it pass.

but from each box, i can still run following, and both runs on both boxes.

https://dns.of.box1:9443/blah/blah
https://dns.of.box2:9443/blah/blah

why azure LB is not allowing traffic generated from load balanced box to come back via load balanced. I am sure, i am not creating infinite loop scenario. and it is a valid use case that a box is running 2 services, and one service wants to use other one via LB, and not directly.

---

update 20190912

so resolve the above mentioned problem, i have till now done this.

added one more nic to the machine. so now azure **VM1** (linux) has 2 nic

1. NIC 1: **A.B.C**.D
2. NIC 2: **A.B.C**.E

(yes, first 3 part of IP are same). Infact all the systems (VM, LB) i am using has that thing similar.

1. now i want traffic that is generating from VM1 to A.B.C.X:9443 should use NIC 1: A.B.C.D
2. and traffic that is generating from VM1 to A.B.C.X:8444 should use NIC 2: A.B.C.E
3. and rest of the traffic can choose any NIC, i dont care much.

*for first 2 rules, end IP is same, just port is different.*

is this possible? can if yes, then is it by using routing table? if yes, 
please help me set routing table.

Answer (score 0):

It is an unsupported scenario and will fail when accessing the Load Balancer from the same VM and Network interface, reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-troubleshoot#cause-3-accessing-the-load-balancer-from-the-same-vm-and-network-interface).

> If your application hosted in the backend VM of a Load Balancer is
>   trying to access another application hosted in the same backend VM
>   over the same Network Interface, it is an unsupported scenario and
>   will fail.
>
> **Resolution** You can resolve this issue via one of the following
>   methods:
>
> - Configure separate backend pool VMs per application.
> - Configure the
>     application in dual NIC VMs so each application was using its own network interface and IP address.

### Update1

For your update, the routing table could not do that as an IP route is a network layer entity. It can not identify the ports which are a transport layer (TCP/UDP) entity.

In your case, you have two NICs, each NIC could bind with its application. From this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-multiple-ip-addresses-portal), Azure also has the ability to add any of the private IP addresses for any of the NICs to an Azure Load Balancer back-end pool. Then you need to make the second nic could communicate outside of its subnet. You have to manually add persistent routes to the operating system vary by distro. Read details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/multiple-nics#configure-guest-os-for-multiple-nics).

Comment: Any update in your question? If you have solved it, you could post your solution here.

Comment: sorry for late reply, just posted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

before posting on how i was able to resolve it. I will like to mention couple of things. I am not that proficient on UNIX routing table configuration. Although AZURE NIC UI interface does give some mechanism to allow/block traffic on basis of source and destination. In reality it did not worked.

so basically i wanted to route traffic b/w 2 apps running on same VM via LB. As per MSFT documentation it is not possible.

so I attached 2 NIC to VM. I binded app1 to nic1, and app2 to nic2. and via telnet i was able to confirm that they were listening on desired IPs. but then I tried lot of things, but I was not able to route outgoing traffic from aap1 to use NIC1, and outgoing traffic from app2 to use NIC2. so LB was still stopping the traffic.

only thing I was able to do, was to route full traffic from VM from either NIC1 or NIC2.

so finally (due to time constraint), i went with most expensive option. I installed app1 on vm1 and app2 on vm2. and now everything is working fine.